# Error in osm data data import while nominatim installation

Tags: linux, php, postgresql

I am doing nominatim installation on my server. I run the following command

```
./utils/setup.php --osm-file /usr/share/osm2pgsql/planetfile/planet-latest.osm.pbf --all
```

to import the pbf file and Few tables are imported successfully and finally at the end of the script I got the following error:

```
/usr/share/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lSc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 24591 -d nominatim /usr/share/osm2pgsql/planetfile/planet-latest.osm.pbfUsing projection SRS 4326 (Latlong)
NOTICE:  table "place" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "keyvalue" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "wordscore" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "stringlanguagetype" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "keyvaluetype" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  function get_connected_ways(pg_catalog.int4[]) does not exist, skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=24591MB, maxblocks=3147649*8192, allocation method=3
Mid: Ram, scale=10000000

Reading in file: /usr/share/osm2pgsql/planetfile/planet-latest.osm.pbf
Entity: line 1: parser error : Document is empty

^
/usr/share/osm2pgsql/planetfile/planet-latest.osm.pbf : failed to parse
Error occurred, cleaning up
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.80.0 (32bit id space)

DB Error: no such table
```

Please suggest what can I do to solve this issue. Give me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The logs imply that `/usr/share/osm2pgsql/planetfile/planet-latest.osm.pbf` is empty... is it?

Comment: No file is not empty. planet file is 16GB and I have also tried with german.pbf it is 1.2GB. And I am facing the same error with both the files... Is it any memory related issue? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
apt-get isntall libprotobuf-c0-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-c-compiler protobuf-compiler
```